# How do I create a map of string indexes in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I want to create a map where the keys are characters in the string and the values of each key are lists of positions of given character in the string.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share what you have so it's clear what part of the problem gets you stuck.

Comment: @Piotrek Bzdyl - I was stuck at Clojure's immutability.

Comment: Usually when you want to create a new structure from an existing structure `reduce` or `loop/recur` are good starting points. The tricky part is figuring out if there is already a higher order function or combination of that does what you are trying to do already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure there are several solutions for this. My first thought was use [`map-indexed`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map-indexed) to get a list of `[index character]` then [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) the collection in to a map.

```
(defn char-index-map [sz]
  (reduce
   (fn [accum [i ch]]
     (update accum ch conj i))
   {}
   (map-indexed vector sz)))


(char-index-map "aabcab")

;;=> {\a (4 1 0), \b (5 2), \c (3)}
```

Comment: I forgot I was going to point out that the ` [i ch]` is destructuring the *tuple* in to the symbols i,ch https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring

Comment: My pattern is usually to use `(fnil conj [])` for this kind of thing, so I don't have to reverse the indexes later.,

Comment: I agree. I usually use `fnil` as well but in this case it isn't apparent that it is needed and `conj` can handle `nil`.

Comment: `(apply merge-with into (map-indexed (fn [i x] {x [i]}) xs))`

Answer (score 6):

a bit shorter variant:

```
(defn process [^String s]
  (group-by #(.charAt s %) (range (count s))))


user> (process "asdasdasd")
;;=> {\a [0 3 6], \s [1 4 7], \d [2 5 8]}
```

notice that indices here are sorted

Comment: the other solution has reverse sorted indices, which might be better for the problem I want to solve.